# jquery-ui theme causes wrong positioning of Dialog layout (close button, size grip misplaced)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, jquery-ui, themes, themeroller

In my rails 3.1 app I am displaying a simple jquery-ui dialog in which close button and size grip get misplaced (see screenshots below).

The code:

html:

```
<p id="dialog">Hello</p>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
 $("#dialog").dialog();
});
```

Very basic thing :) And here are the results I get:

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcGvA.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTSLa.png) (with close button hovered)

Notice that on both of them close button has jumped to the line below, so did size grip.

I used [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to generate me an Overcast theme. I downloaded only theme css+images, because rails already has recent jquery and jquery-ui libs bundled.

I checked versions and they are:

**jQuery:** 1.7.1

**jQuery-UI:** 1.8.16

**jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css (theme css):** 1.8.18

When downloading theme file I was given two choices: theme for jquery 1.3.2 and for 1.3.2+. I have 1.7.1, so I downloaded second one.

Also one interesting fact is that in my older project I have almost the same setup except that I use theme with css version 1.8.14 and buttons are in place!

I know I can switch to using that theme, but then I have no option of generating themes with ThemeRoller! Which I'd really like to. I did check some other themes, but result was the same - misplaced close and sizegrip buttons.

Any hint would be really cool! :)

Comment: It's hard to fix some CSS issue without all the code. Maybe you need inspect it and find by yourself.

Comment: hm. okay. I just posted this in case someone already encountered such problem. I guess i'll have to compare the css of working older theme with new one... what actually bothered me is that it's a clean project with no css customizations applied. Theme is a stock one too. So I thought maybe this is some known jquery-ui/theme issue...

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue as you.  I had to re-download the CSS to include the Dialog.  Once I pointed to the updated CSS everything was working as expected.